# Requested member does not exist? Delphi6 Create Data Source with Word 2013

Tags: delphi, ms-word, automation, mailmerge

We have a system that works on Delphi 2006 that creates a Word data source, we have tried a number of resources but can not seem to find anything on helping us. The problem is that our data source does not create more than one column witch means that it gives us an error of "the requested member does not exist". Please give some insight on this problem, as we think its the format of Word 2013 that gives us issues

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;
  WordApp, NewDoc, wrdMailMerge, wrdDataDoc: OleVariant;

implementation`enter code here`

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
  WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  NewDoc:=WordApp.Documents.Open('c:\temp\TempLetter.doc');
  WordApp.Visible:= True;

  wrdMailMerge:=NewDoc.MailMerge;

  NewDoc.MailMerge.CreateDataSource('c:\temp\DataDoc.doc',,,'SUR_NME,   FUL_NME, NAT_PER_DE, PLACE, BTH_DT');
  wrdDataDoc:=WordApp.Documents.Open('c:\temp\DataDoc.doc');

  wrdDataDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2,1).Range.InsertAfter('arno');

  wrdDataDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2,2).Range.InsertAfter('venter');

  wrdDataDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2,3).Range.InsertAfter('SA');
  wrdDataDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2,4).Range.InsertAfter('ggggp');
  wrdDataDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2,5).Range.InsertAfter(Date);

  wrdDataDoc.Save;
  wrdDataDoc.Close(False);


  wrdMailMerge.Execute(False);

  NewDoc.Saved:=False;
  NewDoc.Close(False);



    enter code here

  end;


end.
```

Answer (score -1):

Word to the wise regarding Office Automation in Delphi: I highly recommend recording a macro in Word while you do your merge manually and have a look at the VBA code that Word generates for the macro.

Once you've got the VBA code, how does it compare with how you're approaching the problem in Delphi?

Sometimes there are simple spelling differences or paths to particular Office Object members that are hard to tease out working solely from the Word documentation.

Good luck.